# Pass a variable into constructor via app->make()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a repo and a eloquentrepo, see code. Now I want to pass a var into the constructor via the `app->make()`

Is that possible and how can I achieve that?

AppServiceProvoder:

```
app()->bind(TestRepository::class, EloquentTestRepository::class);
```

Appmake:

```
app()->(TestRepository::class)->getItem(TestModel::TEST_ITEM);

class EloquentTestRepository implements TestRepository {
    __construct($var){
        // do something with the $var
    }
}
```

Try:

```
app()->(TestRepository::class,['test'])->getItem(TestModel::TEST_ITEM);

public function __construct(  $test)
{
    echo $test;
}

Error:

Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $test ]]
```

Solution:
In the AppServiceProvider:

```
    app()->bind(FrequentieRepository::class,
        function($test){
            return new EloquentTestRepository($test);
        });
```

Comment: I might be missing something but you're not calling the `make()` method. `$this->app->make(TestRepository::class, ['test' => 'Yes'])...`. Also see `makeWith()` - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#the-make-method

Comment: See edit, AppServiceProvoder, so i make a bind in the serveprovider and call the app->make() in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter can be an array of arguments, check it [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L732).

**Illuminate/Foundation/Application**

```
/**
 * Resolve the given type from the container.
 *
 * (Overriding Container::make)
 *
 * @param  string  $abstract
 * @param  array  $parameters
 * @return mixed
 */
public function make($abstract, array $parameters = [])
{
    $abstract = $this->getAlias($abstract);
    if (isset($this->deferredServices[$abstract]) && ! isset($this->instances[$abstract])) {
        $this->loadDeferredProvider($abstract);
    }
    return parent::make($abstract, $parameters);
}
```

Comment: can you please add my solution to your answer, then i can accept your answer :)

Comment: @Bas you can accept it if it makes sense to you, does your solution work?